# Update size keeps increasing? What could be causing this?

Tags: updates, appcenter

I've noticed that when I close and reopen AppCenter, the size of the updates keeps on increasing, as seen in these screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVkjU.jpg

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: newer updates? i noticed elementary updates are quite frequent, even several times a day - maybe there are new ones in the queue? you can check what's to be updated and the size of update with 'sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade' (it will ask for confirmation before installing the updates, there you can see the queue)

Answer (score 0):

As Jena mentioned in their comment, it is new updates being pushed through. Elementary OS is being patched and updated very quickly. The updates stack upon each other and grow in size over time.